# how to dynamically bind output from one cdk class to another cdk class

Tags: python-3.x, aws-cdk

So I have 2 different classes in python created in CDK.
one class is `LambdaAutomationTaskStack` that creates few lambda functions and links them to step functions task using lambda invoke.
so in short `LambdaAutomationTaskStack` creates a list type variable `lambda_attached_task_names` that contains lists of tasks associated with the lambdas.

```
class LambdaAutomationTaskStack(cdk.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: cdk.Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        self.lambda_attached_task_names = list()
        self.lambda_attached_task_names.append(self.prepare_check_lambda_function_a())
        self.lambda_attached_task_names.append(self.prepare_check_lambda_function_b())

    def prepare_check_lambda_function_a(self):
        check_lambda_function_a = _lambda.Function(self, 'lambda_function_a',
                                                    code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambdas/lambda_function_a'),
                                                    handler='lambda_function_a.handler',
                                                    function_name=f'lambda_function_a',
                                                    runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
                                                    timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
                                                    )
        check_lambda_function_a_as_task = sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, 'check_lambda_function_a_as_task',
                                                                   lambda_function=check_lambda_function_a,
                                                                   result_path='$.check_function_a')
        return check_lambda_function_a_as_task

    def prepare_check_lambda_function_b(self):
        check_lambda_function_b = _lambda.Function(self, 'lambda_function_b',
                                                   code=_lambda.Code.from_asset('lambdas/lambda_function_b'),
                                                   handler='lambda_function_b.handler',
                                                   function_name=f'lambda_function_b',
                                                   runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_8,
                                                   timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
                                                   )
        check_lambda_function_b_as_task = sfn_tasks.LambdaInvoke(self, 'check_lambda_function_b_as_task',
                                                                 lambda_function=check_lambda_function_b,
                                                                 result_path='$.check_function_b')
        return check_lambda_function_b_as_task
```

Another class `StepFunctionAutomationStack` accepts this `list of tasks` variable `lambda_attached_task_names`  as part of the input to the step-function cdk stack.

Now in this class how I have created a `definition`  like below:

Let say my `lambda_attached_task_names` has 2 values it should create definition like this:

```
definition = sfn.Chain.start(check_lambda_function_a_as_task)\
            .next(check_lambda_function_b_as_task)
```

Let's say I have 5 tasks in my `lambda_attached_task_names` then definition should looks like this:

So, I made the change to create the definition like this:

```
definition = "sfn.Chain.start"
        for index, value in enumerate(task_details):
            if index == 0:
                definition += "(" + str(value) + ")"
            elif index < len(task_details) - 1:
                definition += ".next(" + str(value) + ")"
            else:
                definition += ".next(" + str(value) + ")"
```

Now, If I passed this to my state machine:

```
sfn.StateMachine(
            self, "StateMachine",
            definition=definition,
            timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
            state_machine_name='anl-some-stack'
        )
```

Now, this throws me

```
jsii.errors.JSIIError: Expected object reference, got "sfn.Chain.start(<aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke object at 0x7f0f666da650>).next(<aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke object at 0x7f0f672daad0>)"
```

So, how can I get the actual task associated in class `LambdaAutomationTaskStack` to class `StepFunctionAutomationStack`, not as an object?

These two classes are called and reference in the main python `app.py`

Update:
I tried to check the value using this agian in my main app.py

```
for index, value in enumerate(lambda_automation_stack.lambda_attached_task_names):
    print(value.__dict__)
```

this gives me like this:

```
{'__jsii_ref__': CreateResponse(ref='@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks.LambdaInvoke@10013', interfaces=None)}
{'__jsii_ref__': CreateResponse(ref='@aws-cdk/aws-stepfunctions-tasks.LambdaInvoke@10018', interfaces=None)}
```

but If I combine these 2 classes in one class they all work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I typically write CDK code in Typescript, not Python, so bear with me.
It appears you are creating a string for your definition, but the StateMachineProps.Definition property is expecting an IChainable object.
Your code as a result should be constructing a workflow and not a string, something like (forgive me, this is untested):

```
definition = sfn.Chain.start(check_lambda_function_a_as_task)
current_step = definition
for index, value in enumerate(task_details):#assuming task_details is an IChainable object
    current_step.next(value)
    current_step = value

#and leave this code the same
sfn.StateMachine(
  self, "StateMachine",
  definition=definition,
  timeout=cdk.Duration.seconds(30),
  state_machine_name='anl-some-stack'
)
```